# TSQL: Any benefits for explicitly specifying NVARCHAR in a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, nvarchar

When  you add pass a new `job_type` to [`sys.sp_cdc_add_job @job_type`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510626.aspx), 
(which is of type `nvarchar(20)`)

You can pass the argument as either

- `N'`cleanup'
- cleanup

**Are there any reasons or benefits to use the former syntax using `N'` to pass the argument to stored procedures?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only if the string contains unicode characters

The string is implictly converted to nvarchar when the passed into the stored proc.

However, before SP execution, it's a literal varchar ("character string constant") without N prefix. So, if you Japanese names, you'll need "N" to make it a "unicode constant". See "[constants](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx)" in BOL which explains more about, er, constants...

Edit: A test of this inspired by Andomar...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ZanziBar
   @KungFoo nvarchar(1)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT @KungFoo
GO

EXEC dbo.ZanziBar '₠'

EXEC dbo.ZanziBar N'₠'
```

Comment: Both Windows strings and nvarchars are stored in UCS-16.  So I think it's unlikely that a *string is implictly converted to nvarchar*.  It's the other way around: a non-N-prefixed string is converted to some 8-bit encoding, while an N-prefixed string is transmitted "as is".

Comment: @Andomar: it is converted when passed into the stored proc. The calling batch parses it according to the "N"

Answer (score 5):

Most strings in Windows are unicode UCS-16.  Now I didn't write SSMS, but I know SSMS talks to SQL Server using the TDS protocol.  So the logical thing to expect is that SSMS converts `''` strings to an 8-bit TDS string, while it can send `N''` strings as a UCS-16 TDS string without conversion.  Let's see what happens in a test:

```
select '₠', N'₠'
---- ----
?    ₠

(1 row(s) affected)
```

The `?` is what's left of the Unicode-only character, it got lost in the UCS-16 to 8-bit translation.

Since SSMS does not know what type of string a stored procedure expects, I expect it to convert a `''` string in a stored procedure call as well.

The performance penalty should be negligible, UCS-16 to UCS-8 and back is very fast.