# Unable to persist language specific characters into the database column of xml datatype

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, spring-mvc, jpa

I need to save language specific characters in a column of xml datatype, because XML is the format that I want it to be when I retrieve it. Just before persisting, I see the Russian characters in the XML, but what actually gets stored after I persist using JPA are something like '??????'. To be noted, the requirement is to keep the column datatype as xml. I tried whatever I could find on the web, but no success. If anyone could please help me out in this.

I have a function that takes the map containing the language characters, as a one of its parameters. The function converts the map into XML format and returns as string. This is then persisted into the database as:

```
entityManager.persist(X)
```

, where X is an entity object with the XML string mapped into one of it's properties.

```
private String toXML(Map<String, String> map, String root) {
    StringBuilder xmlSB = new StringBuilder(OPEN_NODE);
    // Logic to convert map to XML
    return xmlSB.toString();
}
```

Immediately after entityManager.persist(X), the entry that I see in the database table is something like '????' replacing all the Russian characters in my case, rest everything remaining the same.

Comment: Can you add the underlying SQL and tables please? Basically, you are sending a non-unicode string or it isn't really an XML column. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6857945/27535 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/1694267/27535 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/4767737/27535

Comment: what is the character set and collation you use for database

Comment: @gbn i have the table having a column X, with xml datatype and I dont want to change the datatype to nvarchar. I would appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: xml accepts non-ANSI. You are sending it wrong then

Answer (score -1):

Modify the column collation as **UTF-8** and add the string **characterEncoding=UTF-8** at your jdbc url. This logic is once i used for mysql.

But to store the special characters in mssql, you need to change the datatype of the column is nvarchar() instead of varchar().

Comment: Could you please help me in modifying the column collation as UTF-8 for SQL Server 2008? I guess, here we do not have any option to change the collation in 2005/2008. Ultimately, we would have to resort changing the datatypes, which is not acceptable.

Comment: SQL Server uses UCS-2 via nvarchar data type